# how to hide the keypad after tapping the empty area

Tags: ios, uitableview, becomefirstresponder

I'm trying to make keypad disappear on tapping the empty area (the textfields are in tableViewCells) I'm able to do that with following code

```
    -(void) initTapGesture{    //calling in viewDidLoad

        self.singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTappingView)];
        self.singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        self.singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.singleTap];

    }

-(void)onTappingView{


     [self.tableView endEditing:YES];  // or [self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

but after this the tableView cell's didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method is not being called at all.What should I do??

I also tried the following code for onTappingView function it didn't work :

```
-(void)onTappingView{
    RegistrationTabelViewCell *cell=(RegistrationTabelViewCell*)[self.registerationTabelView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.currentCellIndexPath];

    [cell.textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: What if you remove the UITapGestureRecognizer inside your onTappingView method.

Comment: What do you want to happen with cell selection when you tap in the empty area? Should it select the cell and dismiss the keyboard? Only dismiss the keyboard, and require another click to select?

Comment: On tapping empty area it should dismiss keyboard, its happening in the above code but didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method is not called if i include the tap gesture, and in my app there are other cells in the same tableView where i need to select the cell for navigating to other viewControllers.

Comment: Try this

    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
    {
    return YES;
    }